# Mysql return decimal column as string value based on the other column value

Tags: mysql

I have a table like below

```
id   Hour   Subtask
 ---  ----   --------
 1     5      Coding
 2     0      PTO

I need the output like below

 id   Hour   Sub task
 ---  ----   --------
 1     '5'     Coding
 2     'PTO'    PTO
```

I want to return the hour column as string as mentioned in the output table.

Comment: Logic behind changing `0` to `'PTO'` on row id = 2 ?

Comment: Yes. correct .Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If your logic is change hour to *PTO* when `subtask` is *PTO*,then you can use below:

```
SELECT ID,IF(subtask='PTO','PTO',CONCAT("'",HOUR,"'") as hour,subtask FROM yourtable
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean "*as string mentioned*" as Data Type or as String format?
I guess you do not need a quoted string but the cast value:

`SELECT id, if(Subtask='PTO',Subtask,cast(Hour as char)) Hour, Subtask`

or

`SELECT id, if(Hour=0,Subtask,cast(Hour as char)) Hour, Subtask`